# SQL Server job suddenly running for hours instead of few min without making any changes

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, jobs

I have a SQL Server agent job I am running it daily from 3 years without any issue, generally the job takes less than 10 min. The last 2 days it's running for long time more 4 hours which is extremely slowly although I didn't make any changes, also I don't have any other job running that it can slow down my job. The procedure I am executing looks like this. I drop first my table then insert new values from another view.

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE test
AS

BEGIN
    DROP TABLE mytable
END

BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO mytable
    FROM myview
END

GO
```

I have been checking many threads and investigating how this issue appeared without making any changes but I didn't find a clear explanation.

Any ideas what could be the problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing the contents of the tables, it's hard to say.  Best guess points to lack of indexes or sudden drastic increase in the number of records in the tables that make up `myview`

Comment: You have to do some investigation unless you want to post the URL and login credentials to your database server on [so].... Start with an execution plan, or see if you can replicate this on a copy of the database, use a profiler to see what the reads/writes are, see if there is locking, etc. If you do not know where to start then start with some tutorials on performance troubleshooting on sql server.

Comment: Second guess would be a change to the query that generates `myview`.  Code for that view and a small sample of data might shed some more light on this.

Comment: Yeah, there's not much there to go on.

Comment: @user2366842  it's not related to a drastic increase, as my data has just around 1300 rows more than 2 days ago when it was running fine

Comment: Get an actual execution plan for the query "SELECT * FROM MyView" and paste the image or XML on here.

Comment: an addition of 1300 rows seems unlikely for that sort of time jump.  As @MJH suggested though, the execution plan will give us a much better idea of what's going on.  If this is being executed from a remote machine, there may be network issues interfering with the completion of the job as well?  Really just shooting in the dark without more information.